# Unable to insert data in Sqlite Database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, outputstream

Following code is used to insert data in the database.

When application is launched, following code is executed.

After `RecentDBManager` is executed, when I `PULL` database from emulator memory, it shows no record in `FavoriteScrip` table.

When I logged `InsertStmt` in `setData` method, it works fine.
It shows

`insert into FavoriteScrip(sym,cmp,chg) values ('value1','value2','value3')`

**but it is not getting inserted in table...**

**In main class**

```
 rdbM = new RecentDBManager(CompanyView.this);
                        try {
                            if (!rdbM.checkDataBase()) {
                                rdbM.createDataBase();
                            }
                            rdbM.openDB();
                            rdbM.setData("value1");
                            rdbM.closeDB();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new Error("ERROR in DB Access"+ e.toString());
                    }
```

**RecentDBManager class**

```
    public class RecentDBManager {
    private DatabaseHelper dataHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private Context ctx;
    private String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.mypackage/databases/";
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "ScripMasterDB";
    private static String TABLE_NAME = "FavoriteScrip";
        private String InsertStmt;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Cursor cur;

    RecentDBManager(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        dataHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        Context myContext = null;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w("DBHelper", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        File f = new File(myPath);
        return f.exists();
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        openDB();
        try {
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH+ DATABASE_NAME);

            if (mDb.isOpen())
                mDb.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error("RecentDbManager Exception - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public RecentDBManager openDB() throws SQLException {
        mDb = dataHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void setData(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("sym", value1);
cv.put("dt_tm", "datetime()");
mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            throw new Error("RecentDbManager Exception in inserting data"
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void closeDB() {
        try {
            mDb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I have one column which contains current datetime.

So query is of the form `"insert into " + TABLE_NAME+ " (sym,dt_tm) values ('" + value1 + "',datetime())"`

I tried

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("sym", value1);
cv.put("dt_tm", "datetime()");
mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

**`value1` column is getting inserted into table but not datetime. What can be the problem?**

### Final edit

DONE... I used following :

```
                Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                    String currentdate = dateformatter.format(date1
                            .getTime());
```

and passed `currentdate` as second parameter.

THNX ALL !!!!

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

Comment: have you tried to print logs before and after insertion, what is your logcat displaying..

Comment: i mean have u got any error in your logcat

Comment: No. I got this in log `insert into FavoriteScrip(sym,cmp,chg) values ('value1','value2','value3')` when I logged InsertStmt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Create table Memo (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sym TEXT, cmp TEXT, cng TEXT);
}
```

.

```
public void setData(String value1, String value2, String value3) {

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("sym", value1);
            cv.put("cmp", value2);
            cv.put("cng", value3);

            mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
```

Comment: it worked. But I have one more column which contains current dateTime. How do I add it's value to database?

Comment: rdbM.setData("value1","value2","value3");

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving a blank space after tablename of your insert statement:

```
insert into FavoriteScrip (sym,cmp,chg) values ('value1','value2','value3')

InsertStmt="insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (sym,cmp,chg) values ('" + value1 + "','" + value2                    + "','" + value3 + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead of raw query

Comment: but what if I want to store datetime() column in database. How do I do that using insert?